# How to get WNDCLASS from HWND?

Tags: c++, hwnd

I'm working now with playground SDK and need to get WNDCLASS of my game window. I haven't found anything in SDK, thats why I'm trying to do this with hWnd of game window. So is there any way to get WNDCLASS from HWND?
I need this to change system cursor in game window

Comment: Just curious, but why can't you keep track of the data you passed into `RegisterClass`?

Comment: @AdamRosenfield playground is a cross platform SDK for casual games and it creates the window.

Comment: @ElDorado, Just wondering, as there's not often a need to access the class, what are you doing with it?

Comment: @chris I have no idea what the OP intends to do with the class.

Comment: @IronMensan, Oops, wrong person :p

Comment: @chris Well, lets say, I just NEED this class )

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252574/can-wndclassexlpszclassname-be-set-in-an-mfc-app-cmainframe

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252574/can-wndclassexlpszclassname-be-set-in-an-mfc-app-cmainframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about the SDK in question, but as long as it provides access to the native `HWND` type, you can use native calls.

---

**To change the cursor for all windows of that class:**

Use the `SetClassLongPtr` function:

```
SetClassLongPtr(hwnd, GCLP_HCURSOR, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(newCursorHandle));
```

---

**To change the cursor for just the game window:**

First of all, there is a `WM_SETCURSOR` message that you can handle to take control of what cursor is shown in the window. You can read more about that in Adam Rosenfield's comment below.

That aside, there is an alternative: As per the `SetCursor` documentation, first make sure the class's cursor is set to nothing (`NULL`). Then you can use the `SetCursor` function when the mouse enters and leaves the client area. To not interfere with other windows in the class, be sure to set the class cursor to NULL on mouse entry and set it back to what it was on mouse exit.

```
otherCursor = SetCursor(otherCursor);
```

---

**To get the read-only WNDCLASSEX associated with a window:**

First, use [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the name of the class associated with the window:

```
std::array<TCHAR, 256> className; //256 is max classname length
GetClassName(hwnd, className.data(), className.size());
```

Then, use that in a call to [`GetClassInfoEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
WNDCLASSEX wce;
GetClassInfoEx(GetModuleHandle(nullptr), className.data(), &wce);
```

Now you can access `wce` to read the contents of the class structure. If you need to, you can replace `std::array` with `std::vector` and `.data()` with `&className[0]`, as well as `nullptr` with `NULL`. `GetClassInfo` will return a `WNDCLASS` if you need that instead of `WNDCLASSEX`.

Comment: if I've changed some attributes of WNDCLASS, how must I save it? Something like RegisterClassEx? I've tryed only to change them but it doesn't seems to work right (at least this attribute doesn't saved)

Comment: @ElDorado, What exactly are you changing?

Comment: @ElDorado, I've updated my answer to reflect the different possibilities of what one could need.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Looks like Playground is changing cursor back to system. I've tryed to set .hCursor to NULL due to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648393(v=vs.85).aspx) info. Looks like it worth new post, because this way doesn't work. Anyway thanks a lot, I've learned something out of Your replies

Comment: @ElDorado, It looks to me like this question/answer might benefit some people in the future who come wanting the `WNDCLASS` for whatever reason. That's always a plus.

Comment: @ElDorado: If you to change a window's cursor, you'd be better off overriding its window procedure's [`WM_SETCURSOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message handler.  If you can't change the window procedure, you can [subclass it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633570%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#subclassing_window) instead.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield, I forgot about that option. Thank you very much for bringing it up.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield Thanks a lot! That was the only working wolution for me!