# Can WNDCLASSEX::lpszClassName be set in an MFC-App-CMainFrame?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

(
similar problem as "How to get WNDCLASS from HWND?",[How to get WNDCLASS from HWND?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13369334/how-to-get-wndclass-from-hwnd)
in which WNDCLASSEX is wished to be modificated
)

I have tried to set WNDCLASSEX::lpszClassName 
to be able to identify Window handles from MainFrames of our own MFC-Apps 
(to distinguish from existing Wnds which have the same PID)
(to let them communicate via WM_COPY-DATA-Messages) 
it seems to work in

```
CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT &cs)
// m_hWnd is still NULL, so no dependant Wnds should exist but cs.lpszClass even contains (registered?!) className of the Mainframe-Window
{
  if (cs.lpszClass!=NULL) { // when second call happens
    WNDCLASSEX wce; 
    GetClassInfoEx(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),cs.lpszClass,&wce);
    wce.lpszClassName="Test";
    UnregisterClass(cs.lpszClass,AfxGetInstanceHandle());
    RegisterClassEx(&wce);
    GetClassInfoEx(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),cs.lpszClass,&wce); // wce.lpszClassName="Test" :-)
  };
  if(!CMDIFrameWndEx::PreCreateWindow(cs)) return FALSE;
}
```

but merely with that CMainFrame::LoadFrame returns FALSE and App doesn'r start ...

(
In search procedure we'd like to get

```
// ... HWND hw ;
TCHAR className[256] ;
GetClassName(hw, className, 256);
WNDCLASSEX wce;
GetClassInfoEx(GetModuleHandle(nullptr), className, &wce);
// if (wce.lpszClassName=="Test") ... // Mainframe of own  App
```

)

Martin

Comment: seems to be the solution ...

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/articles/196354/provide-your-custom-class-name-to-your-mfc-applica